# Bootstrap 3 Footer Text Alignment Based on Grid Size

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new to Bootstrap, and started out with v3. I am trying to figure out if there is a way to change the alignment of text (or images) based on which grid size is in effect.

I am designing a footer and it has three columns. The left column's content is left-aligned. The center column's content is centered in its column. The right column's content is right-aligned. This makes a balanced-looking, pleasing footer on all display sizes other than a phone display. On a phone (extra-small grid), I want these three columns to stack and have all of the content centered (even though some of the content is left-aligned or right-aligned at larger display sizes). Right now in my design, they are stacking, but the L-C-R alignment is making it look terrible.

Is there a way to do this, to change the alignment of text by size of grid that's in effect? Please assume I may just not have a basic understanding about something as I am so new to Bootstrap and am not a super-experienced CSS person either. (I muddle along, learning as I go.)

Comment: @adrift - here's the jsfiddle (hopefully I am doing this correctly - first time using jsfiddle): http://jsfiddle.net/cheriep/6XKKr/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done with using the existing media queries in Bootstrap. Since v.3 is mobile first, I would make all the content centered first, and then on the next larger media query (768) add styles to the elements that need to be left and right aligned. I have edited your code a little as well:

**HTML**

```
<footer>
 <div class="container">
   <div class="row">     
     <div class="col-sm-4  ">
       <a href="#"><img src="http://www.kissingerassoc.com/images/1.gif" class="img-responsive center-to-left"/></a>
       <br>
       <br>
    <div class="small center-to-left ">&copy; 2013 Company, Inc.</div>
   </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">
         <div class="text-center">
           <p><a href="#">Host Company, Inc.</a><br>
            <a href="#">Terms of Use</a> | <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></p>
           <p>social media icons</p>
         </div>
     </div>

     <div class="col-sm-4 ">
        <span class="center-to-right">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bullhorn"></span><br>
       Feedback
       </button>
     </span>
     </div>
 </div>
 </div>
</footer>
```

**CSS**

```
.center-to-left {
 display: block;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 text-align: center;
 }

.center-to-right {
 display: block;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 text-align: center;
 }


@media (min-width: 768px) {

.center-to-left {
 text-align: left;
 float: left;
 }

.center-to-right {
 float: right;
 text-align: right;
 }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help - I really appreciate it! I realize now that I wasn't looking at it properly, wasn't thinking about the 'mobile first' aspect in that the base styles weren't reflecting that. Thanks again.